# clarifai- ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, clarifai

I am trying to upload an food image and trying to detect the picture using clarifai food detection model which is in JSON format and display results in my html page I am taking sample code from [here](https://help.clarifai.com/hc/en-us/articles/360061663733-Identify-food-items-in-your-images#classify_food_items_in_a_local_image)

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for ,session
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pandas
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from clarifai_grpc.grpc import api
from clarifai_grpc.grpc.api import service_pb2, resources_pb2
from clarifai_grpc.grpc.api.status import status_code_pb2
from clarifai_grpc.channel.clarifai_channel import ClarifaiChannel
from clarifai_grpc.grpc.api import service_pb2_grpc
stub = service_pb2_grpc. V2Stub( ClarifaiChannel.get_grpc_channel())

app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates',static_folder='static')
app.secret_key='a'


@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def food():
    metadata = (('authorization', 'Key {XXXXXXX}'))
    if request.method =='POST' :
        file = request.files['Image']
        image = Image.open(file)
        my_request =service_pb2.PostModelOutputsRequest(model_id='9504135848be0dd2c39bdab0002f78e9',inputs=[resources_pb2.Input(data=resources_pb2.Data(image=resources_pb2.Image(base64=file.getvalue())))])
        response = stub.PostModelOutputs(my_request,metadata=metadata)
        print(response)
        if response.status.code != status_code_pb2.SUCCESS: 
            raise Exception("Request failed, status code: " + str(response.status.code))
      
        names = []
        confidences = []
        for concept in response.outputs[0].data.concepts:
            names.append(concept.name)
            confidences.append(concept.value)

        return render_template('button.html',img=image,searchResults=names)
    return render_template('button.html')


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True ,host='0.0.0.0')
```

But I get this error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

and it shows error in this particular line

```
response =stub.PostModelOutputs(my_request,metadata=metadata)
```

How do solve this error??
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably remove that PAT from this public website

Answer (score 0):

According to this [API doc example](https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/predict/images#predict-via-url), metadata should be as follows:

```
metadata = (('authorization', 'Key ' + PAT),)
```

You should remove the `{}` in your string.

Comment: I tried your solution I got this exception `Exception: Request failed, status code: 11102`  why my request is not getting through

Comment: I'd suggest you accept the current solution and open a different question for your next question as it is not part of the original question.
For your status code, reference https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/advanced-topics/status-codes/

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the file content, not the file path. `file.getvalue()`  returns the path to the file on your machine, but you should provide its contents using `file.read()` like in the [documentation](https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/predict/images/#predict-via-bytes).